# Find Your Device doesn't lock/erase or indicate it will be completed when phone is online

Tags: samsung, security, lost-phone, remote-wipe

I don't believe these exact questions have been answered, so would appreciate your help!

I lost my Samsung Galaxy S8 while it was on airplane mode. I have been checking Find Your Device frequently, but I have seen no change in the date it was synced (which is the day before I lost it), nor have I been able to locate it.

I tried locking it, but after inputting the information the screen gets stuck in “Trying to contact your phone…”.

I also clicked “Yes, erase” in the “Consider erasing your device” section. The words “Trying to contact your device to erase it…” showed up in the bottom left corner and disappeared within a few seconds. I was left with a screen saying that I could restart these steps at any time:
[image: screenshot]
When I go to the Find Your Device homepage again, there is no record that I tried erasing the phone. The “Yes, erase” option is still there. I tried it multiple times from both of my Gmail accounts. How can I tell that the erase command was sent and will be completed as soon as the device is online? And how can I tell if it has been erased? I did not receive any emails about it.

I did sign out of my Google accounts remotely and change my passwords. Is that why it doesn’t work? I thought I would still be able to track the device after those actions, but I don’t know if I can still lock the phone or erase it. I don’t actually know if the signout and password changes worked, though, because the phone was on airplane mode when I lost it.

Any other advice would be great. Thanks!